# Collection with type classes

Tags: scala

In the process of learning basics of Scala,  I tried a code snippet to model a co-variant collection with type classes for learning purpose.

```
sealed trait PseudoCollection[+T]  

import scala.collection.mutable._

class Box[+T] extends PseudoCollection[T]{

    //private var buffer = ListBuffer[T]()
    //Replacing Any with T causes a compile time error
    private var buffer = ListBuffer[Any]()

    override def toString() = buffer.toString

    def add[A1 >: T](t : A1) =  { buffer += t.asInstanceOf[T] }
} 

sealed trait PreciousMetal
class Gold(val name:String = "Gold") extends PreciousMetal
class Silver(val name:String = "Silver") extends PreciousMetal
class BarGold(override val name:String = "Bar Gold") extends Gold

val preciousMtlBox = new Box[PreciousMetal]()
preciousMtlBox.add(new Gold("Golden Ring"))
preciousMtlBox.add(new Silver("Silver Ring"))

val goldOnlyBox = new Box[Gold]()
goldOnlyBox.add(new Gold("Some golden jewel"))
goldOnlyBox.add(new BarGold("Some golden bar"))

println(preciousMtlBox)
println(goldOnlyBox)
```

1. Instead of ListBuffer[Any], is there any collection (or language syntax) that allows storing co-variant of type T ?
2. If ListBuffer[AnyRef] instead of ListBuffer[Any], code does not compile with following error:

   Note that T is unbounded, which means AnyRef is not a known parent.
   Such types can participate in value classes, but instances
   cannot appear in singleton types or in reference comparisons.
           def add[A1 >: T](t : A1) =  { buffer += t.asInstanceOf[T] }

Is there anyway to syntactically express T is a sub type of AnyRef, something like: add[A1 >: T >: AnyRef] ?

Comment: `List[T]` is covariant: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List.  You could use that, or look at it's implementation to get ideas.

Comment: Mutable covariant collections are a bad idea, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Arrays

Comment: @reactormonk - Indeed, though having a mutable collection inherit from a covariant parent without an insertion-exposing API is fine.